# Anonymous vs Named Functions in JavaScript Module Pattern?

Tags: javascript

Is there any benefit for the following JavaScript module defenition:

```
 var module = (function(){

 var PublicFnc = function(){ // variable declaration 
     alert('hi');
 }

 return {
   f : PublicFnc
 }
 })();

 module.f();
```

Over the following:

```
 var module = (function(){

 function PublicFnc(){ // function declaration 
     alert('hi');
 }

 return {
   f : PublicFnc
 }
 })();

 module.f();
```

Although the second example is more convenient since it is more similar to Java/C# the anonymous methods are used more often and I'm wondering what is the benefit?

*@Alexander, thanks for marking the question as duplicate but I tend to leave it open since I'm asking for the benefits within the context of module patterns and not generally*

Comment: It is basically personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the differences between them can be explained using a concept called **hoisting**

In case:

```
a(); //you cannot call this function before its definition as here var a is undefined

var a = function(){ //function statement
    console.log("Hello World");
}

a(); //this will call the function even before its definition because of hoisting

function a(){ //function definition
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

Also some the function in the above case is assigned a memory space using that variable.

In hoisting, function definition is hoisted and not the function statement.

Read more about hoisting here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Also, when to use statement and when to use definition depends on use case and personal preference

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the only difference. The `.name` property will also be different.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks for the input. Rephrased my statement

Comment: Thats's really one good difference.